# Converting dictionary output to normal output in streamlit

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, for-loop, streamlit

with the help of st.write, i'm getting an output in dictionary format in streamlit. If i'm using st.text also, it's returning an output in same dictionary format. Below is the output and code i'm suing

```
with st.spinner("Seaarching for relevant information.."):
    if button:
      results = search(query, top_k=p, index=index, model=model)
      for result in results:
         # st.write(str(result).replace('{', '').replace('}', '').replace('\'', '\"'))
         st.text(result)
```

[image]

I want the output as below

```
1. 'Pdf': 'July 20, 2016.pdf', 'Content': '1. the general manager/deputy general manager, reserve bank of india, issue', 'Page no': '14'
2. 'Pdf': 'July 20, 2016.pdf', 'Content': 'reserve bank of india department of currency management master circular – 2016-17', 'Page no': '3,3,3,3,3'
3. 'Pdf': 'July 20, 2017.pdf', 'Content': 'currency chests / back offices and closely monitoring the detection of counterfeit notes and maintaining the record of the same. ensuring that only properly sorted and machine examined banknotes are fed into the atms / issued over the counters and to put in place adequate safeguards, including surprise checks, both during the processing and in transit of notes.', 'Page no': '5'
4. 'Pdf': 'July 1, 2020.pdf', 'Content': 'reserve bank of india department of currency management', 'Page no': '2'
5. 'Pdf': 'April 1, 2021.pdf', 'Content': '(slbc),  standing  committee  on  currency  management  (sccm),  state  level security committee (slsc), etc.', 'Page no': '3'
```

Can anyone please help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

```
for i, result in enumerate(results):
   st.write(str(i + 1) + '. ' + str(result).replace('{', '').replace('}', '').replace('\'', '\"'))
```

The output is:

```
1. 'Pdf': 'July 20, 2016.pdf', 'Content': '1. the general manager/deputy general manager, reserve bank of india, issue', 'Page no': '14'
2. 'Pdf': 'July 20, 2016.pdf', 'Content': 'reserve bank of india department of currency management master circular – 2016-17', 'Page no': '3,3,3,3,3'
3. 'Pdf': 'July 20, 2017.pdf', 'Content': 'currency chests / back offices and closely monitoring the detection of counterfeit notes and maintaining the record of the same. ensuring that only properly sorted and machine examined banknotes are fed into the atms / issued over the counters and to put in place adequate safeguards, including surprise checks, both during the processing and in transit of notes.', 'Page no': '5'
4. 'Pdf': 'July 1, 2020.pdf', 'Content': 'reserve bank of india department of currency management', 'Page no': '2'
5. 'Pdf': 'April 1, 2021.pdf', 'Content': '(slbc),  standing  committee  on  currency  management  (sccm),  state  level security committee (slsc), etc.', 'Page no': '3'
```